# Disable multiple sessions per user in Oracle APEX 19.2

Tags: session, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I need to configure APEX 19.2 (working in Tomcat) to allow user working only on one session at the same time and only in one tab (in Google Chrome and Edge).

Right now when I am working on Chrome, I can open Edge and create new session, and work on both.

Using Rejoin session attribute with "enable for all session" value doesn't work with 2 browsers.

Comment: The two browsers use separate cookie stores and caches; they don't share session information, so there's no way I'm aware of to do this (rejoin sessions) across browsers. Also be aware that Oracle does not recommend the use of Rejoin Session  for security reasons unless you also implement workspace isolation. Spawning new sessions as you are observing is actually intentional, to prevent session hijacking.

Comment: What is the functionality you want when a user tries to open a new session (in incognito or in another browser). You could enforce the other session to expire by running an on-new session application process that expires the other session(s) for the user. Check the sessions for the user in the apex_views and use APEX_SESSION.DELETE_SESSION api to clean any other session for the user.

Comment: In summary you suggest i should make a process on new session that should delete all other sessions that user have?

Comment: Why would you do that? What's your aim?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also curious about why you want to do this. Keep in mind, the solution you implement will affect the user experience.

Here's one solution based on Koen's comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58672526/1

That was actually the first solution I gave to someone who wanted to implement this. However, I later learned they were on an old version of APEX so I updated the answer to one that required a custom table. You can view that version too if you like.

The advantage of that solution is that it's easy for you to implement. However, it's worse for the end-user in that they may lose some work in the previous session if, for example, they go back to it and submit a form page with data but it just takes them to the login page and doesn't save their work.

A solution that would be harder to implement, but potentially better for your users would be to use an Ajax-based ping which you record in a custom table. This could tell you which session is a user's "active session". When you haven't seen a ping after N seconds, you may consider it stale and allow a new login to kill it.

Going even further, you could have logic that says if the active session is stale between x and y seconds, prompt the user as to whether or not they want to kill the previous session.

As you can see, the more you do for the user, the more effort you have to put into it yourself.